# Why does VS 2015 SSIS hang when changing expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, ssis-2012

I am using a virtual machine Developer environment at work, and when I change an expression in my Visual Studio 2015 SSIS (from ".xls" to ".xlsx") the whole VS program hangs.

(the expression is located in the properties of a Microsoft ACE.OLE.12.0 connection manager's property).

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**: Error (also posted in comment)

```
Problem signature: Problem Event Name:APPCRASH 
Application Name:devenv.exe 
Application Version:14.0.25123.0 
Application Timestamp:56f22f32 
Fault Module Name:mso40uiwin32client.dll 
Fault Module Version:16.0.4519.1000 
Fault Module Timestamp: 58bed810 
Exception Code:c0000005 
Exception Offset:00166226 
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7 
Locale ID:3081 
Additional Information 1: 5861 
Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2 
Additional Information 3: 5f25 
Additional Information 4: 5f2531ae070278f893fa99352dadd49e
```

Comment: What is the error message you received?

Comment: In VS2015 SSDT, I get this:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:APPCRASH
  Application Name:devenv.exe
  Application Version:14.0.25123.0
  Application Timestamp:56f22f32
  Fault Module Name:mso40uiwin32client.dll
  Fault Module Version:16.0.4519.1000
  Fault Module Timestamp: 58bed810
  Exception Code:c0000005
  Exception Offset:00166226
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:3081
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 5f25
  Additional Information 4: 5f2531ae070278f893fa99352dadd49e

Comment: try running in safe mode. Check my answer update

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea Hadi.  But I found out today that the developer virtual machine I was using had a problem.  Either the VM itself, or the instance of VS / SSDT...  I believe my team will destroy this VM and re-create another one....thanks for your help!

Comment: @Albert if your issue is solved, you have to accept an answer, if no answer provided solved your issue, write your own answer and accept it

Comment: Added error from OP's comment, into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my DEVELOPER virtual machine was broken.

I used a new DEVELOPER VM and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

First try to run visual studio in safe mode

```
Devenv.exe /Safemode
```

I think that you must install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

More details can be found in the following link:

- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/02/connecting-to-excel-xlsx-in-ssis.html?m=1

Another thing that you can try it, is to run the package [under 32-bit](http://bidn.com/Blogs/ssis-basics-running-a-package-in-32-bit-mode)